# How to redirect node on paypal for payment before save in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

I need to add payment functionality on specific node type. After registration user can create a node. But node will be shown when user will pay. And after first time payment user got a role .. Means next time he will create node without payment.

Comment: But here I have simple node type.. Not a commerce.In my condition user can create node. But node will be display to other users when payment will be successes.

Comment: You need to elaborate on your question to demonstrate how it's different. As described, it's nearly the same question.